# Spring Boot Unable to start web server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an unusual problem where we have a spring boot project that works on everyones dev environment except mine.  The error I get is:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
```

We have tried creating a vanilla web project from here: https://start.spring.io/ and tried to launch the generated project with the same error.

I fail to see how this is a configuration error on the project, as

1. It was configured from the spring webstite by spring
2. It works in everyone else's IDE except mine

I have tried various versions of STS IDE with the same JDK (jdk1.8.0_121)
I have updated the STS IDE to 3.9.7 and it still fails - this is the same config as a colleague.

This is the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: how about your `pom.xml`?